# Android custom scroller area

Tags: android

I am developing a map that can be scrolling left right and top bottom. 
What is the best View for that?

I dont want to use WebView. I'd like to use some scroller View wirh a bitmap that is MATCH_PARENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
       android:src="@drawable/pic" 
       android:isScrollContainer="true" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:adjustViewBounds="true">
  </ImageView>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
  </ScrollView>
```